# Available languages in "Manage Website Languages" on EPiServer

Tags: episerver

EPiServer ONLY:

I'm trying to add Greenlandic to an existing website. On my local development machine, the language is available as "kalaallisut (Kalaallit Nunaat)  kl-GL", but when I try enable the same language our on staging server, the language is not available in the list shown on the "Manage Website Languages" screen.

I've also noticed "kalaallisut kl" was availble on my local machine on another site, but not for the site I'm working on now.

What determines which languages are available and how do I enable Greenlandic on our staging server?

Answer (score 1):

EPiServer displays the languages available/registered on the machine, and that depends on the OS. You can check [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) to see which languages are available by default.

You can register the language yourself, see [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You didn't mention which version of EPiServer you're running, so I'm assuming 6/7. In that case on way to register the language is through an initialization module, see [this page on EPiServer World](http://world.episerver.com/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-6/EPiServer-CMS-60/Initialization/) - making sure that the language will be available on all machines/servers.